# Pandas add two column values to new data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Why can I do this:

```
df[df['location'] == '170079']
```

(which then yields some information on the location that I am interested in)

But not this (or at least, it yields an error):

```
df_target = df[(df['location'] == '170079'), (df['location'] == '170078')]
```

How can I create a new Dataframe with two (or more) attribute values of the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new dataframe with multiple conditions on locations, this is a way to do it :

```
df_target = df[df['location'].isin(['170079','170078'])]
```

I invite you to refer to the pandas' documentation about [indexing and selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use element-wise boolean operator like this

```
df_target = df[(df['location'] == '170079') | (df['location'] == '170078')]
```